# UFT recognises OracleFormWindow as Javawindow after Oracle 11G to 12C migration

Tags: oracleforms, uft14

Dev team recently upgraded the Oracle application from 11G to 12C . Post that our automation scripts are failing because now UFT recognises oracleformswindow objects as Javawindow.kindly let me know what needs to be done so UFT can recognise the objects as Oracleformswindow. Thank you in Advance

I need UFT to recognise objects like this:

OracleFormWindow("Tia Logon").OracleTextField("OracleTextField").Enter username

Tried Reinstalling the UFT application but didn't work.please Suggest